# Put questions on StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, questions, comments

can you tell me how can I put questions and get more answers ! what I should do to get more interaction with my posts ! waiting for hours and days maybe months to get an answer or comment is not good ... Really I want some advices , thanks in advance

Comment: Ask good, on-topic questions that have not been asked before.

Comment: Have you tried [this FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)? Specifically the first few questions under "Asking questions".

Comment: First open an account on Stack Overflow [which you don't have](http://stackexchange.com/users/3284378/nomade?tab=accounts). Then see some tips for [how](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) to [ask](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Then ask on-topic, non-duplicate question with appropriate tags. You will get more interaction with you posts.

Comment: And while we're at it: don't use code formatting for random highlighting.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply friends:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should respect these rules:

https://stackoverflow.com/help

And before asking a question also review this checklist and make sure your question fits it:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

(what you obviously don't do)

And after that you will probably just get answers which help you on SO as they are part of programming. Your question shouldn't be here asked, as its a question of the Q&A system and not about programming.

So if you are able to formate a Question that respects all my hints and you have topics which belong over here, then you will get a lot of answers and comments, That I'm sure about ;)

p.s.:
Questions concerning problems or questions with the site SO it self, and not with its topics belong to http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: ok thanks for the reply Zaibis ! i read the help but i put questions and i have not a good interaction with it

Comment: @nomade As I reviewed some of your questions, it doesn't loook to me as where you even trying to give this rule a chance: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist" So I can understand that no one wants to help if there isn't any own investigation visible ;)

Answer (score 0):

- [Ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and you'll get good answers.
- [tag-your-question-with-the-right-tags-to-attract-the-right-community-to-answering-your-question](/questions/tagged/tag-your-question-with-the-right-tags-to-attract-the-right-community-to-answering-your-question)
- If you still haven't got enough attention on your questions, you can place a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on it.
- Share your question on other appropriate websites and forums. I'd advise against cross posting, but share links.